# Git visual studio : are files "excluded from project" versioned?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Is Git versioning files that have been excluded in visual studio ?

i.e. :

Are files that are on disk in my project's directory, but not included in my Visual Studio project, versioned by Git ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rephrase the question to make sure I understand:  "Are files that are on disk in my project's directory, but not included in my Visual Studio project, versioned by Git?"

Files in your project's directory hierarchy will be versioned by Git, whether or not they are included in the VS project.  (This assumes, of course, that: a) they are not ignored due to an entry in .gitignore, and b) you have added them to Git's index.)

I'm guessing the usage scenario here is that you had files in your VS project, you chose to exclude them in VS, and you are wondering if  Git is still paying attention to them ... ?

Comment: Thanks for the rephrasing. And thank you for that quite clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Git files are excluded from Git SCM.  Anything under `.git` is not included.